# Keep the docker container running while stopping and starting the process

Tags: docker, spring-boot

I have a spring boot jar which I am invoking on running a Docker container. Everything is running fine.

Now, there are certain other operations also this jar support. In order to use those operations, I have to invoke the jar again (going inside the container) passing in the required parameters. The problem is that some operations kill the already running process, do whatever change is required then starts the app again. As soon the process gets killed the Docker container also stops.

How to keep the container running during the whole process?

Comment: If you container stop for some operation you can use  ```restart``` funcionality, ```docker run .... restart on-failure```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will not discuss about restarting automatically a killed container, since it would not answer your question (but depending on your situation, you may perhaps ask yourself why this solution does not fit your needs).

The container is stopped when the main process launched by the entrypoint, defined in your image, is killed in the container. So, to avoid stopping the container, use an entrypoint that does not stop when some operations need to restart the java app. More over, this entrypoint could itself launch the operations, it would then be a process controler for your java application.

Here is a Dockerfile with such an example, as you can see the entrypoint is a specific shell, not directly the java container.

```
From [...]
EXPOSE 443
[...]
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin
CMD chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Now, write your entrypoint.sh this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
[...]
# launch your spring boot jar in a subprocess
java -jar target/myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar > /dev/null 2>&1 &
# or
mvn spring-boot:run > /dev/null 2>&1 &

# you may detach your java process from the shell job list, if needed
disown %1

# now wait infinitely for a "docker stop", that should be the only way to stop this container
while sleep 1
do
  echo waiting for this container to be terminated
  # if needed, launch your app again (in case it has been terminated and not relaunched automatically)
  if ! ps auxgww | grep -v grep | grep java
  then
    java -jar target/myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar > /dev/null 2>&1 &
    # or
    mvn spring-boot:run > /dev/null 2>&1 &

    # you may detach your java process from the shell job list, if needed
    disown %1
  fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks, Alexandre. I followed your suggested approach and things are working fine now.